# Why does this custom hook rendered twice even though the state hasn't changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am creating a useInfiniteScroll just to practice making a custom hook.

And this goes like

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const isHitBottom = () => {
  const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;
  return scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight;
};

export function useInfiniteScroll() {
  console.log("RENDERED");
  const ref = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null);
  const [isAtBottom, setIsAtBottom] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const debounced = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      clearTimeout(ref.current);
    }
    ref.current = setTimeout(() => {
      const isBottom = isHitBottom();
      if (isBottom) {
        console.log("HIT BOTTOM");
        setIsAtBottom(true);
      } else {
        console.log("NOT HIT BOTTOM");
        setIsAtBottom(false);
      }
    }, 500);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", debounced);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", debounced);
    };
  }, []);
  return isAtBottom;
}
```

And a simplified version of another component which uses this custom hook is

```js
import React from "react";
import { useInfiniteScroll } from "../../hooks/useInfiniteScroll";

const Content: React.FC<ContentProps> = (props) => {
  useInfiniteScroll();
  return <div>test</div>;
};

export default Content;
```

Whenever the `isAtBottom` state is changed, `RENDERED` gets logged, which is fine.

But the weird part is `RENDERED` gets logged again if I replay without changing the state.

To reproduce, **leaving the scroll position at the middle of the page**,

1. move scroll to the bottom => `HIT BOTTOM` and `RENDERED` gets logged.
2. scroll bit more up => `NOT HIT BOTTOM` and `RENDERED` gets logged.
3. scroll bit more up => `NOT HIT BOTTOM` and `RENDERED` gets logged. (This is the problematic step since I expected it not to be rendered.)
4. scroll bit more up => only `NOT HIT BOTTOM` gets logged.

And the same thing happens to the opposite state.

Why does it render twice?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the default behavior of react, I can reproduce this behavior in this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nb1fqf?file=src/App.js).
I don't know why the component is re-rendered even if the state is the same, you can note that the component is not re-rendered more than twice even if I click multiple times on the same button.

I don't see any problem with this behavior, in your application you are using `useEffect` with an empty array to listen to the scroll event, so it doesn't matter if your custom hooks is called multiple times.

However, the declaration of the `debounce` function could be moved in the `useEffect` handler, it's useless to recreate the `debounce` function at each render.

```
export function useInfiniteScroll() {
  console.log("RENDERED");
  const ref = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null);
  const [isAtBottom, setIsAtBottom] = useState<boolean>(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    function debounced() {
      clearTimeout(ref.current);
      
      ref.current = setTimeout(() => {
        if (isHitBottom()) {
          console.log("HIT BOTTOM");
          setIsAtBottom(true);
        } else {
          console.log("NOT HIT BOTTOM");
          setIsAtBottom(false);
        }
      }, 500);
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", debounced);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", debounced);
  }, [setIsAtBottom]);

  return isAtBottom;
}
```

Comment: Would `strictmode` affect any of this behavior you think?